# Multi-platform MIDI Player library

Tags: ios, macos, c++11

Is there a non-GPL/LGPL multi-platform (Mac, iOS, Linux, Windows, etc.) MIDI player library for C++?  For Windows I can use MCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [rtmidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) multiplateform C++ library.

Comment: Thanks.  But what I am looking for is to playback "*.mid" file (standard MIDI file).

Comment: Maybe could you have a look on http://midifile.sapp.org/ to read Midi file and then use `rtmidi` to play it.